# renameTo() not working for renaming images and returns false

Tags: java, android, file, file-rename

I have an image gallery app, I am trying to rename images using `renameTo()` method but it is not able to change the name of files and returns false. I read many questions on SO for renaming files and all of them suggest for only one method for renaming files - `renameTo()`. Strangely enough, many questions talk about how it is not a good method for renaming files in various conditions.
Is there any other way of renaming files in android? If I use this way only, how to make it work?

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);

        alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        etRenameFile = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        alert.setTitle("Do you want to rename the file?");
        alert.setMessage(" ");
        alert.setView(etRenameFile);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                renameFileAlert();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // what ever you want to do with No option.
            }
        });

        private void renameFileAlert(){
            String renameFile = etRenameFile.getText().toString();
            Log.v(TAG, renameFile + " another");
            String filename= al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(fileIndex);

            File oldFilePath = new File(al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(fileIndex));
            Log.v(TAG,oldFilePath.toString());
            // Log.d("OLDFILEPATH", oldFilePath.toString());  // prints the correct path of the file being selected

            x = al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(fileIndex);
            File renamedFile = new File(x.replace(filename, renameFile));
            Log.v(TAG, renamedFile.toString() + " new name");  //prints new name of the file being entered
            // Log.d("NEWFILE", renamedFile.toString());

            boolean renamed = oldFilePath.renameTo(renamedFile);
            if(renamed){
                Log.v(TAG, "rename done");
            } else Log.v(TAG, "failed");

            notifyMediaStoreScanner(renamedFile);
        }

        public final void notifyMediaStoreScanner(File file) {
//        try {
//            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(),
//                    file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), null);
        getBaseContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(file)));
        getBaseContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(file)));
//        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
    }
```

Comment: whats does `oldFilePath.renameTo(renamedFile)` return?

Comment: returns false @pskink

Comment: so you have the answer for your question

Comment: but why does it return false @pskink

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to rename it to exactly? renameTo() will only return true if and only if the renaming succeeded; returning false otherwise.

Comment: trying to rename it to the new name entered in the editText  using `String renameFile = etRenameFile.getText().toString();`